# Extract all substrings between any permutations of two list items

Tags: python, string, substring

I have a list of strings and a text and I want to find sub-strings in the text that are between one of the items in the first list and one of the items in the second list (with any possible permutation but first items from `list1` and second item from `list2`).

```
text = []
text.append('The cars names are BMW, BENZ and FORD; continue')
text.append('The phones name are Iphone and Samsung.')
list1 = ['car', 'phone', 'PC']
list2 = [';', '.']
```

`list1` and `list2` can have **six** (3*2) permutations.
The desired result should be as follows:

```
output = ['s names are BMW, BENZ and FORD', 's name are Iphone and Samsung']
```

Comment: Why does the second string in your desired output include `phone`, but the first string doesn't include `car`?

Comment: Where exactly did you run into a problem when trying to code it?

Comment: @MarkM Sorry. I wrote wrong.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I only know `matches.append(re.findall(r'phone.+?.', text))`. It does not give the right answer when `.` exists and I have to write for all cases.

Comment: There is zero relation between `list1`, `list2` and your desired result. It even has only two results, not 6.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa In text everything between `(car,;)`, `(car,.)`, `(phone,;)`, `(phone,.)` `(PC,;)`,  `(PC,.)` is expected result.

Comment: Why do `IPHONE` and `SAMSUNG` change to uppercase, is that intentional?

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa I edited,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` to generate all possible pairs of start and end.

We can then build a regex that captures the group between these bounds. We must take care to escape them, as they might contain characters (like `'.'`) that have special meaning in a regex.

We just have to use each regex on each sentence of your text.

```
import re
from itertools import product

text = []
text.append('The cars names are BMW, BENZ and FORD; continue')
text.append('The phones name are Iphone and Samsung.')

list1 = ['car', 'phone', 'PC']
list2 = [';', '.']

bounds = product(list1, list2)
out = []
for start, end in bounds:
    regex = re.compile(re.escape(start) + r'(.*?)' + re.escape(end))
    for sentence in text:
        m = regex.search(sentence)
        if m:
            out.append(m.group(1))
print(out)
# ['s names are BMW, BENZ and FORD', 's name are Iphone and Samsung']
```

Comment: If the first text be `The cars names are BMW, BENZ and FORD. continue.`. It prints `s names are BMW, BENZ and FORD. continue` while it should not print after the first `.`

Comment: Then we just need to make the regex non-greedy by adding a `?` to `.*`. I edited the answer accordingly.